# Most efficient way to delete records from a huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table tblcalldatastore which produce around 4000000 records daily. I want to create a daily job to delete any record order than 24 hours. What is the most efficient and less time taking way? Below query is my requirement.

```
 delete from [tblcalldatastore] 
 where  istestcase=0      
 and datediff(hour,receiveddate,GETDATE())>24
```

Comment: Partiiton by date and use `TRUNCATE TABLE tab WITH (PARTITIONS(x))` or simply drop partition.

Comment: Minor speedup: don't use datediff but precalculate now-24h and delete everything older than that. That eliminates a calculation per record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better approach is to avoid `delete` entirely by using partitions on your table.  Instead of deleting records, drop partitions.

For example, you can create a partition for each hour.  Then you can drop the entire partition for the 25th hour in the past.  Or you can basically have two partitions by day and drop the older one after 24 hours.

This approach has a big performance advantage, because partition drops are not logged at the record level, saving lots of time.  They also do not invoke triggers or other checks, saving more effort.

The documentation on partitioning is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Sorry I clicked that incorrectly as I am new to the website, I have accepted it again. The answer worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You might not want to go down the Partitions route.

It looks like you will typically be deleting approx half the data in your table every day.

Deletes are very expensive...
A much faster way to do this is to

Select INTO a New Table (the data you want to keep)

rename (or Drop) your old Table

Then Rename your new table to the old table name.

This should work out quicker - Unless you have heaps of Indexes & FKs...

Comment: Hi John I tried this method earlier but It is not feasible to create a new table and select into on daily basis. I need to automate it.

Comment: You can automate that table juggling as well